# Finding duplicate and unique nested sequence items using count in Python

Tags: python

```
List1=[1, 2, 2, 3]
```

I like the following to extract duplicate and unique list items.

```
DuplicateItems = [x for x in list1 if list1.count(x) > 1]

[2]
[2]

UniqueItems = [x for x in list1 if list1.count(x) == 1]

[1]
[3]
```

However, can I do the same with nested sequences?

```
List2 = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

All list2 nested sequences containing duplicate second items should be:

```
[2, 2]
[3, 2]
```

While all list2 nested sequences unique second items should be:

```
[1, 1]
[3, 3]
```

I've tried several combinations, but it seems the following should work:

```
DuplicateItems = [x for x in list2 if list2.count(x[1]) > 1] 
UniqueItems = [x for x in list2 if list2.count(x[1]) == 1]
```

It does not work.  What am I doing wrong?  I realize there are other methods to extract duplicate and unique items but I like the simplicity of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is trying to find a single number (`x[1]`) in a list of pairs (`list2`). Here's a solution you can try, using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

# First, extract 2nd items into new list:
counts = collections.Counter(x for _, x in list2)

# Then apply your previous logic:
duplicate_items = [x for x in list2 if counts[x[1]] > 1]
unique_items = [x for x in list2 if counts[x[1]] == 1]
```

**Edit:**

If you'd like to work with arbitrary (but equal) length nested lists (e.g: `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], ...]`), assuming you're still only interested in the last element, you can replace the `counts` line with:

```
counts = collections.Counter(x for *rest, x in list2)  # Python3 only, or
counts = collections.Counter(x[-1] for x in list2)     # All versions of Python
```

Remember to update the indices in `duplicate_items` and `unique_items` too.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly for the question as posed.  However, what if I want to use it with nested sequences containing more than two items?  For instance, List2 = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]?  That returns ValueError: too many values to unpack.  Can _, be replaced with something that works for whatever many items are in a nested sequence?

Comment: counts = collections.Counter([x[-1] for x in list2]) works well.  I thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy array...

```
import numpy as np

list2 = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3]])


DuplicateItems = [x.tolist() for x in list2 if list2[:,1].tolist().count(x[1]) > 1] 
UniqueItems = [x.tolist() for x in list2 if list2[:,1].tolist().count(x[1]) == 1]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was a touch slow testing yours, but also a good answer.